# how can i create a tkinter app updater which is included with the app

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, macos, tkinter

I have a Tkinter app which I have converted to `.app` and `.exe`, but after giving this app to others if I have to update the app how should I do it(like in play store update)? And also if I package this app and distribute with an installer then how to send update to the app?

Comment: For that you need a distribution platform, if ou are sending it standalone, then I think only way is to send them again and ask them to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's possible to update the app like that. Android apps usually are made with Java, and iOS apps are made with Xcode, Swift, and Objective-C. I don't usually make apps with Python, unless they are for myself, because once they are made into apps, they cannot be updated (as far as I know). If I wanted to update my Python app, I would remove the first app, then use Pyinstaller to make the updated app.

Hope this helps, and have a good day. :)